# Modificar valores de columna de JTable

Tags: java, netbeans, datatables, sqlite, jtable

Estoy queriendo modificar los valores de una JTable, aplicando una formula matemática y que sume o reste al valor total cierto porcentaje, (porcentaje que ingresaría el usuario). El problema es que no sé como invocar cada columna por separado o "discriminar" de alguna forma cada columna en la que aplicaría la formula, estoy en blanco.
Desde ya, muchas gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido, es muy importante agregar lo que trataste o investigaste, revisar [ask],y no olvides realizar el [tour] del sitio,  saludos.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: En un programa de Stock y precios, usando una interfaz gráfica de java, agregué un JTextField y un boton, donde el usuario debería ingresar un valor en porcentaje. Tengo una tabla creada, en la cual hay 7 columnas y a las ultimas tres debería aplicar el porcentaje proporcionado. Lo que no puedo hacer concretamente es invocar/llamar a cada columna por separado, o hacer que solo aplique la función matemática a esas tres columnas únicamente.